# Removing duplicates within formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Is it possible to remove duplicate value in column with a formula in it?

[image: It looks like this.]

I would like to remove all the duplicates from columns C and D. Code in column C:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$200;AGGREGATE(15;6;(ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100)-ROW(Sheet2!$A$2)+1)/(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100<>"");ROWS(C$1:C1)));"")`

Comment: can you be more specific. please add images of your desired output and how you got it

Answer (score 0):

Is it alright if the formulas are converted to text?

- Select all the data
- Copy it
- Right click in another sheet, and click the paste with 123 on the icon. (Paste Values)
- Then use 'Remove Duplicates'
- If needed, you can copy the formulas back in again.